# TOR EXIT NODE PORT

Tags: exit-relays

I want to be a tor exit node, I have mentioned "ExitRelay1" but nyx shows ExitPolicy as reject. I don't understand the torrc code at all. Pls help me out.
My internal port 443 is forwarded to port 7372 on my external IP. How can I configure tor to use these ports for its exit node? Pls someone write the codes

Comment: Can just mentioning "ExitPolicy accept *:443" do? Because my 443 isn't forwarded to mypublicIP:443 but to mypublicIP:7372    ?

Comment: nyx shows "exit policy: reject [0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000]/0:*"

Comment: It may help if shows your actual config.

Comment: If you don't understand torrc then please don't run an Exit relay. Take your time to learn before you begin.

Comment: It's really great that you want to help, but Martin is correct. There is a lot to learn before running an exit node and it should not be taken lightly nor is it for beginners. https://blog.torproject.org/tips-running-exit-node

Answer (score 0):

1. ControlPort 9051
2. HashedControlPassword 16:13BEBA1E107F34eF53BC616rrrrrEF730324F26BDF2D
3. ORPort 9001
4. RelayBandwidthRate 100 KB
5. RelayBandwidthBurst 200 KB
6. ContactInfo d4rkven0m jhasaurabh571@gmail.com
7. DirPort 80 NoListen
8. DirPort 127.0.0.1:9091 NoAdvertise
9. ExitPolicy accept *:6660-6667,reject *:*
10. ExitPolicy accept *:119
11. ExitPolicy reject *:*
12. ExitRelay 1    #for middle relay: BridgeRelay 1,for guardrelay:GuardRealay 1